# How to put social plugins in website?

Tags: api, facebook-login, facebook-social-plugins, google-signin

Hi friends i am making my website in PHP and i want to put login buttons of Facebook, Twitter and Google+. I am totally new to APIs.

For Facebook I go through https://developers.facebook.com/ but this code is not running. I mean there is no any output.I just copy following code paste it in my website.

**code**

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
```

Give me some guideline. How to use APIs of all three